# label binding trouble

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, label

So i'm attempting to use a label to display a record I have stored in a table in the DB.  There is only one record in this table.

//declare class at top of page

```
 protected Invoice invoice_Info;

   myDataBase db = new myDataBase();

   invoice_Info =
            (from invoiceInfo in db.Invoice_Infos
             select invoiceInfo).FirstOrDefault();

                labelBindforInvoiceDetails.DataBind();
```

Then in my aspx page I am using:

```
<span>                             
 <asp:Label id="labelBindforInvoiceDetails" runat="server" Text="<%# Bind('invoice_Info') %>"/>                                  
 </span>
```

But the code is throwin me an error with 'bind' Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Answer (score 1):

You need to databind the Header and see if it works then.

```
Page.DataBind()
```

Check this out for another solution http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/64/Bind-Data-From-a-SqlDataSource-to-a-Label

Comment: Instead labelBindforInvoiceDetails.DataBind();, i've tried both of them together and still getting the same error. Any other suggestions? thanks for the reply

Comment: Did you put the code I gave you on Page_Load instead of DataBinding the Label?

Comment: I am pretty sure you do not need to bind this object to your  label to make it work. What are the properties of invoice_Info? You can just set the text of your label to one of the properties that will contain what you need.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. A label is not a databound control. Put the label inside of a Repeater (which is a databound control). Then the controls inside (i.e. your label) can be bound.

OR

take the bind out and just do this in code behind

```
            labelBindforInvoiceDetails.Text = invoice_Info.ToString()
```

Comment: ok so iv tried labelBindforInvoiceDetails.Text = invoice_Info.ToString();  in code behind and in aspx: <asp:Label id="labelBindforInvoiceDetails" runat="server"/>, all it displays is 'invoice_info'

Comment: ok then you must need a property of invoice_Info rather than the whole object